# Finding Contiguous Matching Locations in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of locations and want to find the first location (or set of locations) different from the first location. By 'different' I mean a distinctly different location based on a function that determines their distance. Here's an example array:

```
[
  {lat: 45, lng: 45},           // 1st Location
  {lat: 45.01, lng: 45.01},     // 1st Location
  {lat: 55, lng: 55},           // 2nd Location - MATCH
  {lat: 55.01, lng: 55.01},     // 2nd Location - MATCH
  {lat: 54.99, lng: 54.99},     // 2nd Location - MATCH
  {lat: 55, lng: 55},           // 2nd Location - MATCH
  {lat: 65, lng: 65},           // 3rd Location
  {lat: 65.01, lng: 65.01}      // 3rd Location
]
```

In the example above the result should be an array containing only the 2nd locations. Assuming locations are matching if they're within 0.2 lat/lng.

My current solution is to:

1. Get the location of the first item
2. Loop thru the remaining locations and if the location is different from the first location, `slice` the array from the index of that location
3. Loop thru the remaining locations and if the location is different from the first, `splice` the array to remove the remaining

Here's a sloppy implementation of it:

```js
var locations = [
  {lat: 45, lng: 45},
  {lat: 45.01, lng: 45.01},
  {lat: 55, lng: 55},
  {lat: 55.01, lng: 55.01},
  {lat: 54.99, lng: 54.99},
  {lat: 55, lng: 55},
  {lat: 65, lng: 65},
  {lat: 65.01, lng: 65.01}
];

const startingLocation = locations.splice(0,1)[0];

const first = locations.findIndex(location => {
  const { lat, lng } = location;
  return newLocation(startingLocation.lat, startingLocation.lng, lat, lng);
});

const validLocations = locations.slice(first);

const newLatLng = validLocations[0];

const last = validLocations.findIndex(location => {
  const { lat, lng } = location;
  return newLocation(newLatLng.lat, newLatLng.lng, lat, lng);
});

if (last > -1) {
  validLocations.splice(last);
}

console.log(validLocations)

// Helper function to test if locations are the same
// For demo purposes only
function newLocation(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {
   return Math.abs(lat1 - lat2) + Math.abs(lng1 - lng2) > 1
}
```

This requires multiple loops thru the locations, and is difficult to follow. Is there a way to simplify this, by reducing the time complexity and/or making it easier to understand?

Comment: This is basically a [string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm), for which many different algorithms exist.

Comment: @Bergi I can see how it might be solved using string matching, but it doesn't seem like a great solution. Can you post an example?

Comment: Oh wait, it seems I misunderstood your problem. Only the title "*Finding Contiguous Matching in Array*" reminded me of the string matching problem.

Comment: Got it. I had a hard time trying to explain the issue in the question, which might be way its not getting much attention. Any input?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution with two loops is simple, straightforward and efficient. There's no reason to change anything about this. However, you shouldn't `slice` and `splice` any arrays too often, it's sufficient to find the first and last index of your match in the initial array - then `slice` once in the end.

Also your code can be simplified a lot:

```
const firstMatch = findIndexFrom(locations, differentTo(locations[0]), 1);
if (firstMatch == -1) return [];
const afterMatch = findIndexFrom(locations, differentTo(locations[firstMatch]), firstMatch+1);
if (afterMatch == -1) return locations.slice(firstMatch);
else                  return locations.slice(firstMatch, afterMatch);

function differentTo(target) {
  return function(location) {
    return Math.abs(target.lat - location.lat) + Math.abs(target.lng - location.lng) > 1;
  };
}
function findIndexFrom(arr, pred, index) { // unfortunately the native `findIndex` doesn't take a start position like `indexOf`
  for (; index < arr.length; index++)
    if (pred(arr[index], index))
      return index;
  return -1;
}
```